# How to download and save an image in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, imagedownload

How do you download and save an image from a given url in Android?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

### Edit as of 30.12.2015 - The Ultimate Guide to image downloading

---

*last major update: Mar 31 2016*

---

***TL;DR a.k.a. stop talking, just give me the code!!***

> Skip to the bottom of this post, copy the `BasicImageDownloader` (javadoc version [here](https://github.com/vad-zuev/ImageDownloader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/so/example/tools/BasicImageDownloader.java))
>   into your project, implement the `OnImageLoaderListener` interface
>   and you're done.
>
> **Note**: though the `BasicImageDownloader` handles possible errors
>   and will prevent your app from crashing in case anything goes wrong, it will not perform
>   any post-processing (e.g. downsizing) on the downloaded `Bitmaps`.

---

Since this post has received quite a lot of attention, I have decided to completely rework it to prevent the folks from using deprecated technologies, bad programming practices or just doing silly things - like looking for "hacks" to run network on the main thread or accept all SSL certs.

I've created a demo project named "Image Downloader" that demonstrates how to download (and save) an image using my own downloader implementation, the Android's built-in `DownloadManager` as well as some popular open-source libraries. You can view the complete source code or download the project [on GitHub](https://github.com/vad-zuev/ImageDownloader/).

> **Note**: I have not adjusted the permission management for SDK 23+ (Marshmallow) yet, thus the project is targeting SDK 22 (Lollipop).

In my ***conclusion*** at the end of this post I will share *my humble opinion* about the proper use-case for each particular way of image downloading I've mentioned.

Let's start with an own implementation (you can find the code at the end of the post). First of all, this is a **Basic**ImageDownloader and that's it. All it does is connecting to the given url, reading the data and trying to decode it as a `Bitmap`, triggering the `OnImageLoaderListener` interface callbacks when appropriate.
The advantage of this approach - it is simple and you have a clear overview of what's going on. A good way to go if all you need is downloading/displaying and saving some images, whilst you don't care about maintaining a memory/disk cache.

> Note: in case of large images, you might need to [scale them
>   down](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

--

Android [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) is a way to let the system handle the download for you. It's actually capable of downloading any kind of files, not just images. You may let your download happen silently and invisible to the user, or you can enable the user to see the download in the notification area. You can also register a `BroadcastReceiver` to get notified after you download is complete. The setup is pretty much straightforward, refer to the linked project for sample code.

Using the `DownloadManager` is generally not a good idea if you also want to display the image, since you'd need to read and decode the saved file instead of just setting the downloaded `Bitmap` into an `ImageView`. The `DownloadManager` also does not provide any API for you app to track the download progress.

--

Now the introduction of the great stuff - the libraries. They can do much more than just downloading and displaying images, including: creating and managing the memory/disk cache, resizing images, transforming them and more.

I will start with [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), a powerful library created by Google and covered by the official documentation. While being a general-purpose networking library not specializing on images, Volley features quite a powerful API for managing images.

You will need to implement a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class for managing Volley requests and you are good to go.

You might want to replace your `ImageView` with Volley's `NetworkImageView`, so the download basically becomes a one-liner:

```
((NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.myNIV)).setImageUrl(url, MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader());
```

If you need more control, this is what it looks like to create an `ImageRequest` with Volley:

```
     ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 
             new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   //do stuff
                }
            });
```

It is worth mentioning that Volley features an excellent error handling mechanism by providing the `VolleyError` class that helps you to determine the exact cause of an error. If your app does a lot of networking and managing images isn't its main purpose, then Volley it a perfect fit for you.

--

Square's [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a well-known library which will do all of the image loading stuff for you. Just displaying an image using Picasso is as simple as:

```
 Picasso.with(myContext)
       .load(url)
       .into(myImageView);
```

By default, Picasso manages the disk/memory cache so you don't need to worry about that. For more control you can implement the `Target` interface and use it to load your image into - this will provide callbacks similar to the Volley example. Check the demo project for examples.

Picasso also lets you apply transformations to the downloaded image and there are even [other libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) around that extend those API. Also works very well in a `RecyclerView`/`ListView`/`GridView`.

--

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is an another very popular library serving the purpose of image management. It uses its own `ImageLoader` that (once initialized) has a global instance which can be used to download images in a single line of code:

```
  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, myImageView);
```

If you want to track the download progress or access the downloaded `Bitmap`:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, myImageView, opts, 
 new ImageLoadingListener() {
     @Override
     public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                     //do stuff
                }

      @Override
      public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                   //do stuff
                }

      @Override
      public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                   //do stuff
                }

      @Override
      public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                   //do stuff
                }
            }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                   //do stuff
                }
            });
```

The `opts` argument in this example is a `DisplayImageOptions` object. Refer to the demo project to learn more.

Similar to Volley, UIL provides the `FailReason` class that enables you to check what went wrong on download failure. By default, UIL maintains a memory/disk cache if you don't explicitly tell it not to do so.

**Note**: the author has mentioned that he is no longer maintaining the project as of Nov 27th, 2015. But since there are many contributors, we can hope that the Universal Image Loader will live on.

--

Facebook's [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) is the newest and (IMO) the most advanced library that takes image management to a new level: from keeping `Bitmaps` off the java heap (prior to Lollipop) to supporting [animated formats](http://frescolib.org/docs/animations.html) and [progressive JPEG streaming](http://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html).

To learn more about ideas and techniques behind Fresco, refer to [this post](https://code.facebook.com/posts/366199913563917/introducing-fresco-a-new-image-library-for-android/).

The basic usage is quite simple. Note that you'll need to call  `Fresco.initialize(Context);` only once, preferable in the `Application` class. Initializing Fresco more than once may lead to unpredictable behavior and OOM errors.

Fresco uses `Drawee`s to display images, you can think of them as of `ImageView`s:

```
    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/drawee"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    fresco:fadeDuration="500"
    fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/placeholder_grey"
    fresco:failureImage="@drawable/error_orange"
    fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
    fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
    fresco:retryImageScaleType="centerCrop"
    fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"
    fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
    fresco:roundAsCircle="false" />
```

As you can see, a lot of stuff (including transformation options) gets already defined in XML, so all you need to do to display an image is a one-liner:

```
 mDrawee.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url));
```

Fresco provides an extended customization API, which, under circumstances, can be quite complex and requires the user to read the docs carefully (yes, sometimes *you need to* RTFM).

I have included examples for progressive JPEG's and animated images into the sample project.

---

#### Conclusion - "I have learned about the great stuff, what should I use now?"

> *Note that the following text reflects my personal opinion and should
>   not be taken as a postulate.*

- If you only need to download/save/display some images, don't plan to use them in a `Recycler-/Grid-/ListView` and don't need a whole bunch of images to be display-ready, the **BasicImageDownloader** should fit your needs.
- If your app saves images (or other files) as a result of a user or an automated action and you don't need the images to be displayed often, use the Android **DownloadManager**.
- In case your app does a lot of networking, transmits/receives `JSON` data, works with images, but those are not the main purpose of the app, go with **Volley**.
- Your app is image/media-focused, you'd like to apply some transformations to images and don't want to bother with complex API: use **Picasso** (Note: does not provide any API to track the intermediate download status) or **Universal Image Loader**
- If your app is all about images, you need advanced features like displaying animated formats and you are ready to read the docs, go with **Fresco**.

In case you missed that, the [Github link](https://github.com/vad-zuev/ImageDownloader) for the demo project.

---

And here's the `BasicImageDownloader.java`

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class BasicImageDownloader {

    private OnImageLoaderListener mImageLoaderListener;
    private Set<String> mUrlsInProgress = new HashSet<>();
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public BasicImageDownloader(@NonNull OnImageLoaderListener listener) {
        this.mImageLoaderListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnImageLoaderListener {
        void onError(ImageError error);      
        void onProgressChange(int percent);
        void onComplete(Bitmap result);
    }


    public void download(@NonNull final String imageUrl, final boolean displayProgress) {
        if (mUrlsInProgress.contains(imageUrl)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "a download for this url is already running, " +
                    "no further download will be started");
            return;
        }

        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap>() {

            private ImageError error;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mUrlsInProgress.add(imageUrl);
                Log.d(TAG, "starting download");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                mUrlsInProgress.remove(imageUrl);
                mImageLoaderListener.onError(error);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                mImageLoaderListener.onProgressChange(values[0]);
            }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(imageUrl).openConnection();
                if (displayProgress) {
                    connection.connect();
                    final int length = connection.getContentLength();
                    if (length <= 0) {
                        error = new ImageError("Invalid content length. The URL is probably not pointing to a file")
                                .setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_INVALID_FILE);
                        this.cancel(true);
                    }
                    is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), 8192);
                    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte bytes[] = new byte[8192];
                    int count;
                    long read = 0;
                    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        read += count;
                        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        publishProgress((int) ((read * 100) / length));
                    }
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());
                } else {
                    is = connection.getInputStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                if (!this.isCancelled()) {
                    error = new ImageError(e).setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_GENERAL_EXCEPTION);
                    this.cancel(true);
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (is != null)
                        is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (result == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "factory returned a null result");
                    mImageLoaderListener.onError(new ImageError("downloaded file could not be decoded as bitmap")
                            .setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_DECODE_FAILED));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "download complete, " + result.getByteCount() +
                            " bytes transferred");
                    mImageLoaderListener.onComplete(result);
                }
                mUrlsInProgress.remove(imageUrl);
                System.gc();
            }
        }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    public interface OnBitmapSaveListener {
        void onBitmapSaved();
        void onBitmapSaveError(ImageError error);
    }


    public static void writeToDisk(@NonNull final File imageFile, @NonNull final Bitmap image,
                               @NonNull final OnBitmapSaveListener listener,
                               @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format, boolean shouldOverwrite) {

    if (imageFile.isDirectory()) {
        listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError("the specified path points to a directory, " +
                "should be a file").setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_IS_DIRECTORY));
        return;
    }

    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        if (!shouldOverwrite) {
            listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError("file already exists, " +
                    "write operation cancelled").setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_FILE_EXISTS));
            return;
        } else if (!imageFile.delete()) {
            listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError("could not delete existing file, " +
                    "most likely the write permission was denied")
                    .setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED));
            return;
        }
    }

    File parent = imageFile.getParentFile();
    if (!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
        listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError("could not create parent directory")
                .setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED));
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (!imageFile.createNewFile()) {
            listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError("could not create file")
                    .setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED));
            return;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        listener.onBitmapSaveError(new ImageError(e).setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_GENERAL_EXCEPTION));
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        private ImageError error;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                image.compress(format, 100, fos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = new ImageError(e).setErrorCode(ImageError.ERROR_GENERAL_EXCEPTION);
                this.cancel(true);
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            listener.onBitmapSaveError(error);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            listener.onBitmapSaved();
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
  }

public static Bitmap readFromDisk(@NonNull File imageFile) {
    if (!imageFile.exists() || imageFile.isDirectory()) return null;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

public interface OnImageReadListener {
    void onImageRead(Bitmap bitmap);
    void onReadFailed();
}

public static void readFromDiskAsync(@NonNull File imageFile, @NonNull final OnImageReadListener listener) {
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap != null)
                listener.onImageRead(bitmap);
            else
                listener.onReadFailed();
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

    public static final class ImageError extends Throwable {

        private int errorCode;
        public static final int ERROR_GENERAL_EXCEPTION = -1;
        public static final int ERROR_INVALID_FILE = 0;
        public static final int ERROR_DECODE_FAILED = 1;
        public static final int ERROR_FILE_EXISTS = 2;
        public static final int ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED = 3;
        public static final int ERROR_IS_DIRECTORY = 4;


        public ImageError(@NonNull String message) {
            super(message);
        }

        public ImageError(@NonNull Throwable error) {
            super(error.getMessage(), error.getCause());
            this.setStackTrace(error.getStackTrace());
        }

        public ImageError setErrorCode(int code) {
            this.errorCode = code;
            return this;
        }

        public int getErrorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: What about the onPictureTaken() callback which gives the picture as byte[], can one get a URL to that picture, straight from the camera? Or is basic old outputStream() the only way in Android to save a picture which was taken by a camera without using the built in intent? That seems strange, because the natural thing to do after onPictureTaken is of course to save it. Is there no particular support for doing that?

Comment: @Tombola Hi! This post is about downloading a picture from the web. But to answer your question (as far as I've understood it): the common way of saving a camera picture is getting its path from the `Cursor` (in the `onActivityResult()` method), then creating a `Bitmap` using that path. And yes, you will not get away from using a `FileOutputStream` and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` if you want to save this image to SD.

Comment: @BartBurg this question is about downloading and saving an image. But you're right at some point, since there's a write method, there also should be a read method for the sake of completeness. I will add it in the next update to this post soon.

Comment: Can you please provide an example using this BasicImageDownloader ?

Comment: @JaydevKalivarapu please check the demo app on GitHub ([source class containing example](https://github.com/vad-zuev/ImageDownloader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/so/example/activities/ImageActivity.java))

Comment: This is what _basic_ looks like on Android. Yay.

Comment: @lukecross I absolutely agree that nowadays you should't do something like this. We have tons of image loaders, we have file downloaders, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines... basically this class is an answer to "how do I download and display an image with plain Java without any frameworks" and is provided for purely educative purposes.

Answer (score 35):

I have just came from solving this problem on and I would like to share the complete code that can download, save to the SD Card (and hide the filename) and retrieve the images and finally it checks if the image is already there. The url comes from the database so the filename can be uniquely easily using id.

First, create a class for Downloading Images.

```
private class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    private String requestUrl, imagename_;
    private ImageView view;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private FileOutputStream fos;

    private GetImages(String requestUrl, ImageView view, String _imagename_) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.view = view;
        this.imagename_ = _imagename_;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        if (!ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename_)) {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create a class for saving and retrieving the files.

```
public class ImageStorage {
    public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

        String stored = null;
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), ".your_specific_directory");//the dot makes this directory hidden to the user
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpg");
        if (file.exists())
            return stored;

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            stored = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stored;
    }

    public static File getImage(String imagename) {
        File mediaImage = null;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root);
            if (!myDir.exists())
                return null;

            mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/.your_specific_directory/" + imagename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaImage;
    }

    public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + imagename + ".jpg");
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (path != null)
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        if (b == null || b.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, to access the images first check if it is already there; if not then download.

```
if(ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename)) {
    File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/"+imagename+".jpg");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    if (path != null){
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
} else {
    new GetImages(imgurl, imageView, imagename).execute() ;
}
```

Comment: **Note**: while this example could generally work, it does not provide any error handling and also lacks some basic understanding of `AsyncTask`'s advantages (proper use of parametrization, parallel execution..). Please refer to my examples below for details. 

**P.S**. for those who might think I wrote this to promote my own code for whatever reason: nope, I'm just pointing out the issues I can see in the given example.

Comment: Yes Droidman, I agree with you. This piece of code should be taken as a tamplate and one has to complete it on his own, including error handling. By the way, your code lacks error handling too. What will happened to your connection and streams in case of IOException?

Comment: @Androider please take a closer look at my `download` method, particularly the `doInBackground` method of the task that I use. An `IOException` would land in the `catch (Throwable e)` block, resulting in an `ImageError` being returned and the `onError()` callback being triggered. The `ImageError` object will contain the original stack trace and the cause of the occurred `Exception`

Comment: Yes, but your connection will not be disconnected and your streams will not be closed

Comment: @Androider ah, I see your point. Though I never noticed any suspicious leaks on my test devices, this behavior might be different on other devices. Thanks for the hint - I have updated the code

Comment: anyway these methods are no longer in much use one could use volley for simplifying the image downloading process

Answer (score 13):

This code might help you.

```
Button download_image = (Button) bigimagedialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_downloadimage);
                    download_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        boolean success = (new File("/sdcard/dirname")).mkdir();
        if (!success) {
            Log.w("directory not created", "directory not created");
        }

        try {
            URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            String data1 = String.valueOf(String.format("/sdcard/dirname/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outstream);
            byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

            stream.write(byteArray);
            stream.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a simple solution which is working perfectly. The code is not mine, I found it on this [link](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-download-and-save-image-internally/). Here are the steps to follow:

**1.** Before downloading the image, let’s write a method for saving bitmap into an image file in the internal storage in android. It needs a context, better to use the pass in the application context by getApplicationContext(). This method can be dumped into your Activity class or other util classes.

```
public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String imageName) 
{
    FileOutputStream foStream;
    try 
    {
        foStream = context.openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, foStream);
        foStream.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.d("saveImage", "Exception 2, Something went wrong!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**2.** Now we have a method to save bitmap into an image file in andorid, let’s write the AsyncTask for downloading images by url. This private class need to be placed in your Activity class as a subclass. After the image is downloaded, in the onPostExecute method, it calls the saveImage method defined above to save the image. Note, the image name is hardcoded as “my_image.png”.

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String TAG = "DownloadImage";
    private Bitmap downloadImageBitmap(String sUrl) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(sUrl).openStream();   // Download Image from URL
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);       // Decode Bitmap
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception 1, Something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadImageBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        saveImage(getApplicationContext(), result, "my_image.png");
    }
}
```

**3.** The AsyncTask for downloading the image is defined, but we need to execute it in order to run that AsyncTask. To do so, write this line in your onCreate method in your Activity class, or in an onClick method of a button or other places you see fit.

```
new DownloadImage().execute("http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png");
```

The image should be saved in /data/data/your.app.packagename/files/my_image.jpeg, check this post for accessing this directory from your device.

**IMO this solves the issue! If you want further steps such as load the image you can follow these extra steps:**

**4.** After the image is downloaded, we need a way to load the image bitmap from the internal storage, so we can use it. Let’s write the method for loading the image bitmap. This method takes two paramethers, a context and an image file name, without the full path, the context.openFileInput(imageName) will look up the file at the save directory when this file name was saved in the above saveImage method.

```
public Bitmap loadImageBitmap(Context context, String imageName) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    FileInputStream fiStream;
    try {
        fiStream    = context.openFileInput(imageName);
        bitmap      = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fiStream);
        fiStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("saveImage", "Exception 3, Something went wrong!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

**5.** Now we have everything we needed for setting the image of an ImageView or any other Views that you like to use the image on. When we save the image, we hardcoded the image name as “my_image.jpeg”, now we can pass this image name to the above loadImageBitmap method to get the bitmap and set it to an ImageView.

```
someImageView.setImageBitmap(loadImageBitmap(getApplicationContext(), "my_image.jpeg"));
```

**6. To get the image full path by image name.**

```
File file            = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("my_image.jpeg");
String imageFullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

**7.** Check if the image file exists.

File file            =

```
getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("my_image.jpeg");
if (file.exists()) Log.d("file", "my_image.jpeg exists!");
```

8. To delete the image file.

   File file            = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("my_image.jpeg");
   if (file.delete()) Log.d("file", "my_image.jpeg deleted!");

Answer (score 2):

Code for download image in android studio:

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = 
         (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility
         (DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded", 
       FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.SUCCESS, false).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

this code perfectly run in my project

```
downloadImagesToSdCard(imagepath,imagepath);

private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl,String imageName)
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("www.xxx.com"+downloadUrl); 
                /* making a directory in sdcard */
            //  String sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
                 // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
                File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                File myDir = new File(directory,"folder");

                /*  if specified not exist create new */
                if(!myDir.exists())
                {
                    myDir.mkdir();
                    Log.v("", "inside mkdir");
                }

                /* checks the file and if it already exist delete */
                String fname = imageName;
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                Log.d("file===========path", ""+file);
                if (file.exists ()) 
                    file.delete (); 

                /* Open a connection */
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)ucon;
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                /*if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                {
                    inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }*/

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
                int totalSize = httpConn.getContentLength();
                int downloadedSize = 0;   
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) >0 ) 
                {                 
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                }   

                fos.close();
                Log.d("test", "Image Saved in sdcard..");  
                viewimage();
            }
            catch(IOException io)
            {                  
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {                     
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } 

        public void viewimage()
        {
              String path = serialnumber+".png";
               ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());

                //path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dirName
                File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                File mypath=new File(directory,"folder/"+path);

                Bitmap b;
                try {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(mypath));
                //  b.compress(format, quality, stream)
                    profile_image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the contribution. Note that the above approach of saving the image on app's private storage has 2 downsides: 1) the image will be only available to your app and 2) you should avoid saving images to app's private storage since it's not intended for large content.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
 try
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    URL url = new URL("Your_URL");
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                    if(f.exists())
                        f.delete();
                    f.createNewFile();
                    Bitmap bitmap = bmp;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fos.write(bitmapdata);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    Log.e(TAG, "imagepath: "+f );
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class testCrop extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView iv;
    String imagePath = "https://style.pk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/omer-Shahzad-performed-umrah-600x548.jpg";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testcrpop);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testCrop);
        imageDownload image = new imageDownload(testCrop.this, iv);
        image.execute(imagePath);
    }
    class imageDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
        Context context;
        ImageView imageView;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        InputStream in = null;
        int responseCode = -1;
//constructor.
        public imageDownload(Context context, ImageView imageView) {
            this.context = context;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap data) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(data);
            saveImage(data);
        }

        private void saveImage(Bitmap data) {
            File createFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"test");
            createFolder.mkdir();
            File saveImage = new File(createFolder,"downloadimage.jpg");
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveImage);
                data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT[image]**

**Make sure you added permission to write data in memory**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Droidman post is pretty comprehensive. Volley works good with small data of few kbytes. When I tried to use the 'BasicImageDownloader.java' the Android Studio gave me warning that the AsyncTask class should to be static or there could be leaks. I used Volley in another test app and that kept crashing because of leaks so I am worried about using Volley for the image downloader (images can be few 100 kB).

I used Picasso and it worked well, there is small change (probably an update on Picasso) from what is posted above. Below code worked for me:

```
    public static void imageDownload(Context ctx, String url){
    Picasso.get().load(yourURL)
            .into(getTarget(url));
}
private static Target getTarget(final String url){

    Target target2 = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File file = new File(localPath + "/"+"YourImageFile.jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Google tells, for now, don't forget to add also readable on external storage in the manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Source : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission