# It is possible in android to retrieve image from MySQL database and display it in imageview?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am going to create an activity feed like this:

[image: Activity Feed]

and I wonder, how will I retrieve the image and how to store it in my MySQL database. Help me out!

Comment: You have to save only image path in database and retrieve image using that path

Comment: Yes it is possible.. You can save it as byte[] array or you can save image path or image name in your database and access it..

Comment: How can i access it if i use php? i have saved an image in my cpanel (it is a host/domain) and i paid for it.

Comment: @IamAndroida: Refer link given in my answer you should get idea how to deal php with android ..

Comment: @Angel i am retrieving using image path itself but i am getting the dummy image file which is default in android emulator but i cant find my image in emulator while compiling

Comment: i have posted the code what @Angel pls check on it where i must correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010339/i-am-retrieving-an-image-from-mysql-using-json-but-getting-error-in-android?noredirect=1#comment35147944_23010339

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the Image
2. Save it as string in database

Here is how to do it

1. To download the image use the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

   ```
   ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
   imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
   OR
   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new
       ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
       .maxImageWidthForMemoryCache(800)
       .maxImageHeightForMemoryCache(480)
       .httpConnectTimeout(5000)
       .httpReadTimeout(20000)
       .threadPoolSize(5)
       .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 3)
       .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
       .build();
   imageLoader.init(config);
   options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
       .showStubImage(R.drawable.loading)
       .cacheInMemory()
       .cacheOnDisc()
       .build();
   imageLoader.displayImage(ProductsImageURL,imagView,options, new ImageLoadingListener(){});
   ```

In this ImageLoadingListener you get a method that is called when loading is done and save the image as string

or make any http connection to download the image as here [How to download and save an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android)

2. Once the image is downloaded convert it into string and store it in database

   ```
   public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
       try {
           byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                   encodeByte.length);
           return bitmap;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.getMessage();
           return null;
       }
   }

   public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
       String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
       return temp;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the general steps if you want to store the image itself into your database.

i. Retrieve the image using its URL and keep it in memory as a byte[]. There are several ways to do this, including creating a ByteArrayBuffer and appending bytes to its end. You can then retrieve the final byte[] with ByteArrayBuffer.toByteArray().

ii. You need to create a table with a column of type BLOB, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE image (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, url TEXT, data BLOB)
```

iii. You would then insert the image byte[] as you would any other data type, for example by create a ContentValues and then passing it to SQLiteDatabase.insert().

iv. Retrieve the byte[] from SQLite and build an image. Use Cursor.getBlob() to grab the byte[] and then do:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayImageStream = new ByteArrayImageStream(yourByteArray);
Bitmap yourImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(byteArrayImageStream);
```

Comment: Is this applicable using a hosted database? im not using SQLitedtabase, im using mysql database and i also use php as bridge between android and mysql

Comment: That is a completely different scenario, however it seems perfectly doable. Here is the first link I found when I searched for "php download image to mysql": http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql  Once you save the image into MySQL, you just need to have your Android app call into PHP and get the image out.