# I want to download a file programically in android but when run,it closed?

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

I think my connection failed but I cant Repair code.

```
URL url = new URL( imageURL);
File file = new File(fileName);
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

when debug it crashed in this part of code.
I use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: What says the crash report? ie the logcat output

Comment: check my related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android/15549639#15549639

Comment: unfortunately,mayapp has stopped

Comment: check the log, what does it say.

Comment: Copy your `LogCat` report and paste in our question.

Comment: I think your logcat contains `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. To be sure, copy the error from your logcat

Comment: execute this in Asynctask or a thread. You must be executing it on your main UIthread like onCreate()

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

Comment: Glenn
It is quite true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below code into your MainActivity  after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above android 3.0 you need to do all your networking in a seperate thread.
So if you try that code in the main thred it will throw a NetworkOnMainThread exception.

try this to verify it:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL( imageURL);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
}
catch (android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ex){
    // Skipp.
}
```

If your app doesn't crashes this way then you need to use an AssyncTask for the networking. 
[Here is a good examplehow to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) .

And don't forget to check your filepath as well like @LucianNovac suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the file like this:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(extStore, fileName);
```

and don't forget to put in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also to avoid Network exception put this into an asynk

```
class DownloadMyFIle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, DownloadProcess> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected DownloadProcess doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(extStore, fileName);
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(DownloadProcess process) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 

    }
}
```