# downloading content and image and save it into sdcard in android

Tags: android, download

Hi In My application I am parse the data through json by passing the URL and displaying image with content.

After That i Added one button if i click the button i want to download the content and image and save it into sdcard.Now,If i press download button it showing unfortunately error.

Now I want if i press download button i want to download the full content with image and save on to sdcard.

can anyone please help me.

**notify_image class**

```
public class notify_image extends Activity {


    Activity av=notify_image.this;
     ImageView imageView;
     View content;
     Button download;
     Activity activity;
     Button btnShowProgress;
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     ImageView my_image;

    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.notify_image);


         imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imageview);
         btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        // download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Intent in = getIntent();

         String title = in.getStringExtra("TAG_TITLE");
         String url = in.getStringExtra("TAG_URL");
         String name = in.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
         String place = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PLACE");
         String date = in.getStringExtra("TAG_DATE");
         final String URL =url;
         TextView stitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
         TextView sname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
         TextView splace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place);
         TextView sdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);  

         // displaying selected product name
         stitle.setText(title);
         sname.setText(name);
         splace.setText(place);
         sdate.setText(date);






         // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
         GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
         // Execute the task
         task.execute(new String[] { URL });
         btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(URL);
            }
        });
         //download();

     }
     class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }
        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }   



      }


     //image url convert to bitmap

     private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
         @Override
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
             Bitmap map = null;
             for (String url : urls) {
                 map = downloadImage(url);
             }
             return map;
         }

         // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
         }

         // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
         private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
             Bitmap bitmap = null;
             InputStream stream = null;
             BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

             try {
                 stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                 bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                         decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                 stream.close();
             } catch (IOException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
             }
             return bitmap;
         }

         // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
         private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                 throws IOException {
             InputStream stream = null;
             URL url = new URL(urlString);
             URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

             try {
                 HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                 httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                 httpConnection.connect();

                 if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                     stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                 }
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
             return stream;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Logcat Errors**

```
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at com.politicalmileage.vel.notify_image$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(notify_image.java:122)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at com.politicalmileage.vel.notify_image$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(notify_image.java:1)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-15 14:27:26.457: E/AndroidRuntime(14670):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? post your logcat error information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android please follow this

Comment: Hi HAR i posted my logcat errors can you check it out let me know what  i did wrong

Comment: Have you instantiated pDialog object?

Comment: Thank you but it's download image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));` but `pDialog` is not set and is equal to `null`. You have to set your variable for the error in your LOG CAT.

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```