# How to provide large set of images in Android?

Tags: android, assets, android-resources

I want to use a large set of images in my application, that are used in a gallery view. However using the res folder seems not possible with larger set off images. What is the best way for including the images into my apk?

Comment: Define "large". Hundreds? Thousands? Megabytes? Gigabytes?

Comment: 15MB, about 300images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the images in a database and add your database to the apk (a way to do so described [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). You would read images from the database using [Cursor.getBlob](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#getBlob(int))

Answer (score 0):

Storing all the images in the res folder will be quite a hefty job so what I recommend is that you save all the images on a web server. And then retrieve the required images from their respective URL's. The following link has a full tutorial on retrieving images from a particular URL. 
[How to download and save an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android)
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. my app should work without network or usage of external storage. is there still a way to manage the images?