# Android downloader app

Tags: android

Which approach is the best for the video downloader app? Download manager or url.openConnection. I want the user to be able to download as many files as he wants simultaneously and also enable him to abort the download of any individual file wenever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it's possible if you have url of photo, video, song or whatever... Take a look this theme on stack overflow :

[How to download and save an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, I m gonna have a look at the link.

Comment: Which approach is the best for the video downloader app? Download manager or url.openConnection. I want the user to be able to download as many files as he wants simultaneously and also enable him to abort the download of any individual file wenever he wants.