# Change images in the downloaded apps

Tags: android

I need to change some images in my app, but after edition it in the Google Play. How can I do it? For instance, now in my app there is a picture Bitmap Pic1 with a red quadrate on it. But after a month it will be a picture Bitmap Pic1 with a yellow triangle (name and adress in the app are the same, changing just drawing).

Comment: Are you talking about the icon?

Comment: No, I mean bitmaps inside the app. For example, background picture. I think about Jsoup - by this way it's possible to load text data, but I don't know if it possible to load pictures with this library.

Comment: You should let the app download the picture from a URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android

Comment: I think, that in my situation it will be better refresh apk-file, not download single pictures, because when I will download the picture, I should save it on sd-card and it's not good. Who tell me, how to refresh apk-file (by downloading from the web) from inside the app? I want to create a button, to push it to start a process of downloading the apk-file, but I don't know how.

Comment: you cant re-fresh apk after publishing unless you update it as a version. What you re-fresh is only the app data.