# How to show twitter image when i fetch twitter tweet post in my android list view?

Tags: android, twitter

how to get tweet post with image and display it on list view? 
i'm only getting text in retrieving tweet post on twitter.

this is what i wanted to do http://tinypic.com/r/2ztee84/8
and this is what I've done on my application http://tinypic.com/r/zkmknm/8

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would help if you provided us with more code. But... Try to "parse" the image link from the tweet, and download it.

You could try [this lib](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), which will download images asynchronously. Or you could try a native approach. Something like:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.login);

   this.findViewById(R.id.userinfo_submit).setOnClickListener(this);
   // Verify Code
   LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.txt_verify_code);
   view.addView(new VerifyCodeView(this));

   // show The Image
   new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
   .execute(“http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png”);
   }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
    finish();
  }

  private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String… urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(“Error”, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}
```

This code was taken from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120802025411/http://developer.aiwgame.com/imageview-show-image-from-url-on-android-4-0.html).

And there's this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android), which might be an interesting read for you.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mauker, but i need to display it not to download but anyway thanks again.

Comment: Oh. I see. Downloading is one option. But I'll update my answer later.