# How to add a set as wallpaper button

Tags: wallpaper

Hello everyone I am creating an online wallpaper app.Where users can access wallpaper online.i want add two button  first one is set as wallpaper and second one is download button .So if anybody help me about this I will be thankful to them thanks.

public class GalleryDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra_image";


private ImageView mImageView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(EXTRA_IMAGE)) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_IMAGE)).into(mImageView);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I use  Picasso and json for downloading image for server

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make sure you have permission to make such action. Add in your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

To download the image hosted in some site you could use a 'doInBackground Thread' as suggested below:

[How to download and save an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android)

The button to set the wallpaper is created by code below:

```
Button setWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON);
ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_PREVIEW);
imagePreview.setImageResource(YOUR_IMAGE_RESOURCE);

setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(YOUR_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}});
```

YOUR_IMAGE could be a local resource, like:

```
R.drawable.myImageFile
```

The link in the answer there are several ways of how to download your online image. Please, check it and try set up your wallpaper with local images first.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourfile.jpg");
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
File jpg = new File(path);

if(jpg.exists()) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    WallpaperManager m=WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

    try {
        m.setBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What will I put in image _resource my source is online

Comment: Need more clues.. I am using Picasso and json for downloading image in background so what is my image source give me some clarification thanks

Comment: please, try to use a local file. See the edit answer to know how to do that. After local file works good, click at suggested link and choose the answer best fits your problem.