# Android: How can i make an Image Download Button when Image-Url is given and save it on internal storage

Tags: android, image, download, storage, internal

I have a String with an url to an image.

Can somebody give me the code to realize it?

All what ive done before is not working.

code so far:

```
 dlbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DownloadImage().execute(id);
            }
        });

  public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String imageName)
    {
        FileOutputStream foStream;
        try
        {
            foStream = context.openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, foStream);
            foStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("saveImage", "Exception 2, Something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private String TAG = "DownloadImage";
        private Bitmap downloadImageBitmap(String sUrl) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(sUrl).openStream();   // Download Image from URL
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);       // Decode Bitmap
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception 1, Something went wrong!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            return downloadImageBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            saveImage(getApplicationContext(), result, "my_image.png");
        }
    }
```

> public Bitmap loadImageBitmap(Context context, String imageName) {
>       Bitmap bitmap = null;
>       FileInputStream fiStream;
>       try {
>           fiStream    = context.openFileInput(imageName);
>           bitmap      = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fiStream);
>           fiStream.close();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           Log.d("saveImage", "Exception 3, Something went wrong!");
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return bitmap; }

but nothing happens.
no stored image in gallery and no toast will be shown

Comment: "All what ive done before is not working." Ok, what have you done before?

Comment: i testet some scripts, but i cant get it working

Comment: Ok, what scripts? what wasn't working? We're not going to code this for you, tell us what you've done and where your stuck. Just saying "it's not working" isn't going to cut it.

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android/44780787#44780787

Comment: What code are currently using? Add it to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use Picasso Library for this task

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: i dont want to display the image. i want download to the device storage.