# load images from string url and open them in gallery

Tags: java, android

I am getting the image url in string format from a webservice, i am displaying these images in my app, but when the user clicks on it i want them to load in the users default gallery.I have used the following intent but this doesnt work

```
Uri path = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(jsImage.getJsImageServerUrl()).build();
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android) or [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427440/how-to-download-image-and-save-it-to-gallery-on-android) to save an Image. I am guessing you know already how to detect the click. Then to save it, just use that answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont want to save the image anywhere on the phone, cant i directly display it in gallery ??